# Comparing similar words in two different columns

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, comparison, similarity, column

i have list of different categories in same dataset in two different coulumns

[image: Example data how the comparison should be]

There are some similar words in the two columns. So by comparing the two columns the maximum matched wordings should be created in new column as shown in attached image. Is their any formula that we can compare two columns.

Comment: Can you add the table as text to the question

Comment: There is no way for any code to know that words like `alternativemedicine` is actually two words instead of one word unless you are utilizing a massive English-language dictionary lookup. Excluding the combined words issue, you are simply looking for the longest word (or combined word) in `Cat_2` that starts with the same letter as the word in `Cat_1`.  In general, i don't know if most people consider two words that start with the same letter 'similar' by nature, so I would avoid using that word and stick with what you appear to be asking, which is words that start with the same letter.

Answer (score 1):

Use longest common substring. It is available as native expression:

```
longest_common_substring("Cat_1","Cat_2")
```

---

Update: Honestly I am not sure if I understand your question, but seems like you need to do some tweaking with it, maybe like:

```
with_variable('results',array_distinct(array_foreach(array_agg("Cat_1"),longest_common_substring(@element,"Cat_2"))),@results[array_find(array_foreach(@results,length(@element)),array_max(array_foreach(@results,length(@element))))])
```

Comment: This works if both columns are ordered the same but it doesn't seem to be the case here based on the data provided

Comment: @LouisCottereau sounds like you are right.. took a look again and not sure if I understand the question, some tweaking like the updated A maybe is it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyqgis with [difflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings). It will split the words in the second column by dot, and find the most similar word to column 1:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

fieldlist =["cat1","cat2"] #The two fields to analyze
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Refactored")[0]
field_to_calc = "bestmatch" #The field to store best match word in. Add before you execute the code

attributemap = {} #A dictionary to hold feature id, fieldindex and best match

fieldindex = layer.fields().indexOf(field_to_calc) #Find the index of the field to calculate

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    firstword = f[fieldlist[0]]
    otherwords = f[fieldlist[1]].split(".") #Split the second columns words into a list

    ratios = [[word, SequenceMatcher(None, firstword, word).ratio()] for word in otherwords] #Calculate the similarity for each word in second column compared to first columns word
    #[['professional', 0.2222222222222222], ['advertising', 0.3076923076923077]]

    best_match = sorted(ratios, key=lambda x: x[1])[-1] #Sort by ratios and pick the highest one [-1]
    #['advertising', 0.3076923076923077]

    attributemap[f.id()]={fieldindex:best_match[0]}
    #{1: {2: 'professional'}, 2: {2: 'advertising'}}

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap)
```

[image]